# Sending HTML select tag to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, forms, websocket

I have a html select tag after user select value I want to send that value to the server:

```
  <form id ="eventForm" action="/" method="post">

         <select name="aaaa"> 

            <option value="abc"> ABC</option>
            <option value="def"> def</option>
            <option value="hij"> hij</option>   
            </select>


        <input type="submit" id="open" value="Submit Query" />
    </form>
```

The javascript that sends it is this:

```
$.post("/", $("#eventForm").serialize());
```

However it is not received by the server at all. This does work when I send data in a form as input type text. Thus why wouldn't it send the selected data in the select tag?

Thanks

Comment: First thing's first, `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: Off hand I would say that you must not have an element selected when the post occurs. `serialize()` will only serialize elements with input data.

Comment: @JoelEtherton, I tried with an element selected and nothing is sent through.

Comment: @ Christian, what does var_dump($_POST) do?

Comment: Dr Molle my code I posted works for you?

Comment: yes, of course, there is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Ok....thats strange then it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web server module wasn't picking it up as attribute was named wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured that when the selected option is disabled(html) it just doesn't get sent at all and is ignored as a parameter... I suggest to put up a sort of `try-catch` mechanism on the server side...

P.S.: Good luck on your project!